# KNN classifier not working in python on raspberrypi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, knn

I am writing a KNN classifier taken from [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-to-implement-k-nearest-neighbors-in-python-from-scratch/) for character recognition from accelerometer and gyroscopic data.But, the below functions are not working correctly and prediction is not happening.Are there any mistakes in below code? kindly guide me.

trainingset-> training data with 20 samples(10=A,10=B).

testset-> live reading taken for recognition.

```
#-- KNN Classifier Functions ----------
def loaddataset():
    global trainingset
    with open('imudata.csv','rb') as csvfile:
            lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
            dataset = list(lines)
            for x in range(len(dataset)):
                    trainingset.append(dataset[x])

def euclideandistance(instance1,instance2,length):
    distance = 0
    for x in range(length-1):
            instance1[x] = float(instance1[x])
            instance2[x] = float(instance2[x])
    for x in range(length-1):
            distance += pow((instance1[x]-instance2[x]),2)
    return math.sqrt(distance)

def getneighbours(trainingset,testinstance,k):
    distances = []
    length = len(testinstance)-1
    for x in range(len(trainingset)):
            dist = euclideandistance(testinstance, trainingset[x],length)
            #print(trainingset[x][-1],dist)
            distances.append((trainingset[x],dist))
    #print(distances)
    distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    #print(distances)
    neighbours = []
    print('k='+repr(k)+'length of distances='+repr(len(distances)))
    for x in range(k):
            neighbours.append(distances[x][0])
    return neighbours

def getresponse(neighbours):
    classvotes = {}
    for x in range(len(neighbours)):
            response = neighbours[x][-1]
            if response in classvotes:
                    classvotes[response] += 1
            else:
                    classvotes[response] = 1
    sortedvotes = sorted(classvotes.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return sortedvotes[0][0]

def getaccuracy(testset, predictions):
    correct = 0
    for x in range(len(testset)):
            if testset[x][-1] is predictions[x]:
                    correct +=1
    return ((correct/float(len(testset))) * 100.0)
#------- END of KNN Classifier Functions -------------
```

My main compare function is

```
def compare():
    loaddataset()
    testset.append(testdata)
    print 'Train set: '+ repr(len(trainingset))
    print 'Test set: '+ repr(len(testset))
    predictions=[]
    k = len(trainingset)
    for x in range(len(testset)):
            neighbours = getneighbours(trainingset,testset[x],k)
            result = getresponse(neighbours)
            predictions.append(result)
            print('>Predicted=' +repr(result)+', actual=' + repr(testset[x][-1]))
    accuracy = getaccuracy(testset, predictions)
    print('Accuracy: '+repr(accuracy)+'%')
```

My output is

```
Train set: 20
Test set: 1
k=20 length of distance=20
>Predicted='A', actual='B'
Accuracy: 0.0%
```

My sample data packet:

```
-1.1945864763443935e-16,1.0000000000000031,0.81335962823925234,1.2678119727931405,4.6396523259663871,3,1.0000000000000013,108240.99999999988,328.99999999999966,4.3008487686466931e-16,1.000000000000002,0.73006871826334618,0.88693535629714804,4.3903300136708818,15,1.0000000000000011,108240.99999999977,328.99999999999932,1.990977460573989e-16,1.0000000000000009,0.8120281400849243,1.3556881217171162,4.2839744646260876,9,1.0000000000000004,108240.99999999994,328.99999999999983,-3.4217816017322454e-16,1.0000000000000009,0.7842111273340705,1.0882622268942712,4.4762484049613418,4,1.0000000000000004,108241.00000000038,329.00000000000114,2.6996304550155782e-18,1.000000000000004,0.76504908035654873,1.1890598964371606,4.2138613873737967,7,1.000000000000002,108241.0000000001,329.00000000000028,7.154020705791282e-17,1.0,0.83945423805187047,1.4309844267934049,3.7008217934312198,6,1.0,108240.99999999983,328.99999999999949,-0.66014932688009009,0.48967404184734276,0.083592048161537938,A
```

I am from hardware and dont know much about KNN, thatswhy I am asking for corrections in my code if any.I added my dataset [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_AuGtUrzoANQUQ5ampzcVYzbmc).

Comment: Not sure why this has anything to do with the Raspberry. It's just non-platform-specific python. Anyway, have you tried your code on the iris dataset where you got this code from? Get the same results from that then apply to your own data. Anyway from what code you show no-one could run your code to test it. And you will have to show your training dataset if you expect people to try fix your code.

Comment: @barny, Added the sample dataset and I am from hardware and dont know much about KNN, thatswhy I am asking for corrections in my code if any.

Comment: Have you verified your code by ensuring it gets same results as for the iris sample using the iris dataset?

Comment: And also if you are asking people to help you with your code, you should provide an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve What you have pasted isn't C so can't be V.

Answer (score 0):

I could see from your data that number of samples is very less that no. of features, that may affect the accuracy of prediction and the number of samples need to be very high. You can't expect to predict everything correctly, algorithms have their own accuracies. Try to check the correctness of this code by using any other well-known datasets like iris Or try to use built-in knn classifier from scikit learn python.